# In BoolQueryBuilder Should clause in not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch2

**My ES Method**

```
public VendorSearchResult searchVendors(String query, Locale country, CostType... costtypes) 
{
    try {

    BoolQueryBuilder bqBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

    bqBuilder.must(new TypeQueryBuilder(VENDOR_INDEXTYPE));

    if (country != null) {
        bqBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("address.countrycode", country.getCountry().toLowerCase()));
    }

    bqBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(query, VENDOR_SEARCHED_FIELDS).type(Type.PHRASE_PREFIX));
    /*
     *Should Clause
     */
    for (CostType costType : costtypes)
         bqBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("vendortype", costType.name()));
    bqBuilder.minimumNumberShouldMatch(1);

    VendorSearchResult sr = elasticSearch(bqBuilder, SORTFIELD, SortOrder.ASC);

    return sr;
}

private VendorSearchResult elasticSearch(QueryBuilder pQueryBuilder, String sortParameter, SortOrder sortOrder,
        String... types) {
    try {
        SearchAction action = SearchAction.INSTANCE;
        SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = new SearchRequestBuilder(client, action);

        searchRequestBuilder.setQuery(pQueryBuilder); 
        searchRequestBuilder.setIndices(VENDOR_INDEX);
        searchRequestBuilder.setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH); 

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(sortParameter)) {
            searchRequestBuilder.addSort(sortParameter, sortOrder);
        }

        SearchResponse response = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();

        return convertSearchResponse(response);
}
```

- When i comment **should** clause then i am able to get result form the Elasticsearch.
- If i uncomment then no results is fetched.

Is ther any other way to use boolQueryBuilder?

What might be the problem?

**CostType**

```
public enum CostType {

/** The parking. */
PARKING("PARKING"),
/** The fuel. */
FUEL("FUEL"),
/** The cardealership. */
VEHICLEDEALER("VEHICLEDEALER"),
/** The creditor. */
FINANCING("FINANCING"),
/** The garage. */
GARAGE("GARAGE"),
/** The insurance. */
INSURANCE("INSURANCE"),
/** The leasing. */
LEASING("LEASING");

/** The cost type. */
private String costType;

/**
 * Instantiates a new cost type.
 *
 * @param costType
 *          the cost type
 */
private CostType(String costType) {
    this.costType = costType;
}

/**
 * Gets the cost type.
 *
 * @return the cost type
 */
public String getCostType() {
    return costType;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.lang.Enum#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return costType;
}
}
```

**JSON Document**

`{
  "_index": "Vendor_Index",
  "_type": "Vendor_Type",
  "_id": "732cfd82-f764-44f5-a5d9-574f4eb7000a",
  "_version": 52,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "vendortype": "FUEL",
    "address": {
      "city": "Heimsheim",
      "housenumber": "1",
      "street": "Römerstr.",
      "countrycode": "de",
      "postcode": "71292",
      "geopoint": {
        "alt": "435",
        "lon": "8.86853",
        "lat": "48.82422"
      }
    },
    "name": "OMV Tankstelle Heimsheim",
    "id": "732cfd82-f764-44f5-a5d9-574f4eb7000a",
    "creationDate": "2014-10-25T18:30:00.000Z",
    "brand": "OMV"
  }
}`

Comment: Can you show how your `CostType` enum looks like as well as a sample document that is supposed to match?

Comment: @Val I have added what you require.

Comment: I suppose your `vendortype` string field is analyzed. You might be able to make it run if you simply lowercase your costType with `costType.name().toLowerCase()`. Can you try it?

Comment: @Val I will try and tell you the result

Comment: @Val I knew every field will be analyzed and converted to lowercase. Thanks for remembering. Its working fine.